# flask-sqlalchemy: map data between 2 tables

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a following two tables in a SQLite3 database:

```
class Golfer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=True)
    scores = db.relationship('Score', backref='associated_golfer', lazy='dynaic')

class Score(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    golfer_name = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('golfer.name'), nullable=False)
```

My `Golfer` and `Score` tables contain the following data respectively:

```
id|name
1|Johnny Metz
2|Cody Blick
3|Zack Bailey

id|score|golfer_name
1|71|Johnny Metz
2|72|Cody Blick
3|68|Cody Blick
4|70|Zack Bailey
5|73|Zack Bailey
6|66|Johnny Metz
```

I'm using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) to fetch the data from these tables. I want to map each name in the `Golfer` table to all of their scores in the `Score` table. Here's what I'm doing so far but it's very messy and inefficient, especially as my data grows:

```
golfers = Golfer.query.all()  # get list of all rows in Golfer table
scores = Score.query.all()  # get list of all rows in Score table
golfer_to_scores = {}
for golfer in golfers:
    golfer_to_scores[golfer] = []
    for score in scores:
        if score.golfer_name == golfer.name:
            golfer_to_scores[golfer].append(score)
print(golfer_to_scores)
# {<Golfer obj>: [<Score obj>, <Score obj>], ...}
```

Is there a simpler way using a SQL operation via Flask-SQLAlchemy? Maybe generate a column in the `Golfer` table which stores a list of all the scores (aka rows in `Score` table) associated with that golfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If relationships are configured properly then just:

```
golfer_to_scores = {golfer: list(golfer.scores) for golfer in Golfer.query.all()}
```

Though it would do one query per golfer, so you may want to do a join.

Comment: `golfer.scores` returns a sql query: `SELECT score.id as score_id, ...`. That's not right is it?

Comment: That did it thanks man! Update your answer and I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: As to why it returns a query instead of a collection of related objects: you've configured the relationship with [`lazy='dynamic'`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders), which is handy for handling large collections that you'd usually not load entirely, but in some limited fashion.